# Empty variable in a Fiber

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

So, I have a `fields` variable which is correctly initialized. My goal is to use it inside a Fiber. Here is the code :

```
console.log(fields); //<--- Here it's OK
Fiber(function () {
    var qry = Connections.findOne({login:fields[1]});
    if (typeof(qry) === 'undefined') {
        console.log('INSERT');
        console.log(fields); //<--- Here, the variable "fields" is empty
        Connections.insert({
            login: fields[1],
            ip: fields[2],
            created_at: Date.now(),
            updated_at: Date.now(),
        });
    } else {
        console.log("UPDATE");
    }
}).run();
```

How can I pass the content of the variable `fields` into the Fiber?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work:

```
var fields = /* whatever */;

Fiber(function (fields) {
  // ...
}).run(fields);
```

If you want to read more about this [look here](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers).

Comment: No problem, it's all in the documentation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what fiber is, but try passing your variable as argument of the function:

```
console.log(fields); //<--- Here it's OK
Fiber(function (fields) {
    var qry = Connections.findOne({login:fields[1]});
    if (typeof(qry) === 'undefined') {
        console.log('INSERT');
        console.log(fields); //<--- Here, the variable "fields" is empty
        Connections.insert({
            login: fields[1],
            ip: fields[2],
            created_at: Date.now(),
            updated_at: Date.now(),
        });
    } else {
        console.log("UPDATE");
    }
}).run();
```

Comment: so i have no idea, i am sorry